# Compare the system time vs the time i fetch it

Tags: java, android, time, system

I am getting error :-
INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stack=android.util.TimeFormatException: String too short -- expected at least 8 characters.

```
public void test() {

    TextView onDeviceTime = (TextView) mNextUIMainActivity.findViewById(R.id.timeOfDay);

    Time onSystem = new Time();
    onSystem.setToNow();
    Time onLauncherDisplay = new Time();
    onSystem.parse(onDeviceTime.getText().toString());
    if (onDeviceTime.equals(onSystem)) {
        System.out.println("Correct time!");
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of String comparission try milli second difference

Comment: @JigarJoshi natak na karis...sarkhi rite javab apavo hoi to aap

Answer (score -1):

Your trying to compare a `Time` object and a `TextView` object.  It sounds like what you really want is `if (onLauncherDisplay.equals(onSystem))`.

Comment: should i compare it with onLauncherDisplay.equals(onSystem) ?

Comment: Yeah but you never really set `onLauncherDisplay`. The way you have it would be like comparing a cat object to a house object... which will never be equal.

Comment: same error message using the if (onLauncherDisplay.equals(onSystem))

Comment: Sounds like the issue is in the parse though. Make sure you have a string in the `TextView` as specified by the [parse](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#parse(java.lang.String)) api.

Comment: no, I gave you a link for what it should look like, check for null and/or empty string before running the parse command.